# is this method to write in file is correct?

Tags: android, android-studio, file-writing

I am working in an android studio. I used the following code to write in the file but the file is not working. can anyone tell me why this code is not working?

```
try {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("accounts.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferedWriter.write(tvUername.getText().toString()+","+tvEmail.getText().toString()+","+tvCPassword.getText().toString()+"\n");
    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "account saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    fileWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: FileWriter needs a full pathbi think. And can you define 'not working'?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine. But in case if it not works:

**Use the code below, it works file**

```
File rootStorage = new File(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("storage/emulated/0"))); 


String actualFileName = new File(rootStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName)


  try {

        File textFile = new File(actualFileName);

        if (textFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File path exists = " + textFile.getAbsolutePath());

            // set to true if you want to append contents to text file
            // set to false if you want to remove preivous content of text
            // file
            FileWriter textFileWriter = new FileWriter(textFile, true);

            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(textFileWriter);

            // create the content string
            String contentString = new String(contents);

            // write the updated content
            out.write(contentString);
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Updaetd text file");

        }
```

**If you need to create a new file then write then use the code below:**

```
   try {

        File file = new File(actualFileName);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File path = " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File Name is sampleDeveloper.txt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File not Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: File rootStorage = new File(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("storage/emulated/0")));                                                                                                                                                                   
 String   actualFileName = new File(rootStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);

Comment: `File rootStorage = new File(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("storage/emulated/0"))); 
`Sorry but that is nonsense. Or use: `File rootStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); `  Or use `File rootStorage = getExternalFilesDir(null); `
`

Comment: `File textFile = new File(actualFileName);` Better:  `File textFile = new File(rootPath, fileName);`